# A Way to Save Desktop Layouts with Multiple Presets

Tags: macos

Anyone know if there's an app that will not just let you save window positions for multi-display setups, but also create presets for different situations?

For example

Client A (saved as a preset)
-all windows open and size to saved positions
-different finder windows open to specific folders and views
-browser open to specific tabs at specific addresses
-terminal opens up directly to desired directory
etc...

Client B (saved as a preset)
-same idea but maybe different programs, finder locations, etc..

I took a look at "Stay" but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.  Also, I'm using El Capitan.  Anything like this out there?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Moom](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/moom/id419330170?l=en&mt=12). You can have different presets for different display configurations.

Comment: So far it seems pretty cool, but I don't think it will open any applications for you, is that correct?  I'm sort of looking for this, but also a way to automate opening a series of applications, with finder navigating directly so specific folders

Answer (score 0):

Use [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/) together with [Bunch](https://bunchapp.co).  See [this](https://bunchapp.co/docs/integration/moom/) for integration details.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant